# Odd Google Analytics sessionDuration Numbers

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

Setting up a dynamic integration of the Visualization API and Analytics. Most of it works fine but for some reason the sessionDuration value seems ridiculously high. For example, taken from Query Explorer and concurs with my API query results, using date range 30 days ago to present,

```
Mar 4, 2019 293,427
Mar 5, 2019 240,622
Mar 6, 2019 127,326
```

The first is 81.5+ hours, or 3.39 days. (Part of this interface converts the seconds values to readable time format.) While one should be happy with a long duration, the stats show the average time spent on pages at around 50 seconds, so something is up. Is it possibly adding all the durations of all visitors?

The params for this query (in both API query and Query Explorer) are 30 days ago to today, dimension ga:date, metrics ga:sessionDuration and a custom dimension2 filter to restrict the results set to a custom segment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is high is because you're pulling session duration metric you should do avg session duration instead: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration

Comment: Thank you, I know about average session duration - I suppose the question could be better rephrased as "how does Google come up with this value?" Is it indeed all sessions in a given period for all users?

Comment: @BillHcu this session duration value is the duration of the individual session. The reason why it is large is because when you pick "Date" as your only dimension, it will sum up all sessions for that day. If you want to know the length of individual sessions, then you need to pick a dimension that's on a session scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since a few months I see extermly high **time on page** on google-analytics that are 10 mins and above, usually coming from social media sources; I checked the tracking and it seems ok, but... anyone else reporting the same?